# Is there any other way to define Toaster

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular js. I am trying to display the error message view `toaster()`. I searched on google, but I didn't find the proper result. When I click on the `cancel()` button, I will get an error saying **toaster is not defined**.

Html : `<button class="btn btn-secondary" ng-show="editMode" ng-click="toggle_cancel()"> Cancel </button>`

Angular Js :

```
 $scope.toggle_erase = function(information){
      toastr.toggle_erase('Are you sure want to delete ?')
       $scope.hideDelay(3000):
}
```

Comment: you need to include `toastr` in your code. Instructions are here - https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include toastr.js and toastr.css files.. Please check the example

```js
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module('myapp',['toastr']);

app.controller('demo',function($scope,toastr){
  $scope.toggle_remove = function(){
    toastr.info('Hello!!');
    toastr.refreshTimer(toastr, 3000);
  }
});
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/angular-toastr/dist/angular-toastr.tpls.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://npmcdn.com/angular-toastr/dist/angular-toastr.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <div ng-app="myapp">
    <div class="container" ng-controller="demo">
      <button class="btn btn-secodary" ng-hide="editMode" ng-click="toggle_remove()"> Delete </button> <br/>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Please go through http://angular-js.in/angular-toastr/

Comment: I have installed toastr through npm. So is it necessary to include the script src

Comment: No.. but make sure these are included and you need to include the module and inject it.. take a look at the above shared link

Comment: I followed the way you insisted. But i got error stating : angular is not defined in ** angular-toastr.tpls.js**

Comment: are you putting toastr as a module dependency?.. You need to load angular first and then toastr..

Comment: I corrected the not defined error. But I am getting **toastr is undefined**, even after passing through the function

Comment: You need to inject into your controller for eg. `app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,toastr) { ... }`

Comment: I have created plnkr. If you find any error , let me know @raghav

Comment: Its working fine. But in my code, it says : toastr undefined. I really donot know how

Comment: In my code , i have declared the controller globally and calling the **toastr**  where ever i required through the function

Comment: You need to inject `toastr` in your controller.. you missed in plukr as well `app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,toastr) { ... }`

Comment: `app.controller('contactslist',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http,toastr)  { $scope.toggle_remove = function(){ toastr.info('Are you sure want to delete ?');
     toastr.refreshTimer(toastr, 3000); }`

Comment: Please do this `app.controller('contactslist',['$scope','$http','toastr',function($sc‌​ope,$http,toastr){`

Comment: Thanks raghav.  Actually i have made some other minute mistake , just now i found

Answer (score 0):

**In javascript** : Your have to include respective **toastr.js & toastr.css** file in you project

```
   //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.js
   //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.css
```

and then use like below :

```
$.ajax({
        url: url
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        async: false,
        success: function(response) {
        toastr.success('your success msg');
        }
        error : function(response){
        toastr.error('your error msg');
        }

       });
```

for more details refer below link : https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr

Comment: I would go with this solution already used John Papa's Toaster many times :)